# Is there work done when you push a book on a table? what about when you lift the book up?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

I know that work, $$ W = \int \vec F \cdot d\vec x$$ is zero if $\vec F \perp \vec x$. This means that if I tried pushing a book directly into the table, I  do zero work on the book. Can the same be said if I put the book on my palm and lift it 90 degrees straight up?

Comment: Hint: if you are lifting the book straight up, what direction is the force in?

Comment: The book does zero work anyway, it's you that is doing the work. It's not just words, it's very important to distinguish between work done **on** the book, as opposed to work done **by** the book. The same idea with gravity. If you push the book horizontally, you are doing work on the book by overcoming friction.

Comment: Why was this question marked active? (Aug 2018)

Answer (score 2):

Moving the book up with a force exerted by your hand would do work on the book.

The reason you wouldn't do any work when you push the book down is because it is not moving. (More precisely, it is not moving in the same direction as the force you applied.)